# Question about multi fields index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, python, django

I'm having an doubt about coumpound indexes in my application. My db engine is Mysql 8.0 with INNODB and my question is the following:

My application has a model called Report with the follwing fields `date`, `currency`, `type`, `company`,`aggregator` and `daily_value`. My applications consumes events from kafka where I receive a `value` that represents a monetary transaction and the corresponding `company`. I'm using django and I make the following query each time I receive an event:

```
SELECT company,currency,date,aggregator,type 
WHERE company=passed_company,currency=passed_currency,
type=passed_type,aggregator=passed_aggregator,
date=RANGE(start_date,end_date)
```

to retrieve the given report for that day if it exists and increment the `daily_value`property with the event `value` or create the report for that day if it doesn't exist. Basically I do a `get_or_create` in Django for the ones who are familiar with this framework.

My question is should I make a coumpound index on `date, currency, type, company, aggregator` to optmimize my query and avoid possible deadlocks? I'm asking this because I will have multiple parallel consumers and I want to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: "RANGE()"??  See https://www.garron.me/en/bits/mysql-select-from-range-dates.html for two ways to specify a date range.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is should I make a coumpound index on date, currency, type, company, aggregator to optmimize my query and avoid possible deadlocks?

That seems reasonable based on your example query's `WHERE` clause using all of those fields. It's generally good to cover all of the fields of the predicates (`JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses) in a query, so optimal operations like seeks can be done against the data.

> I'm asking this because I will have multiple parallel consumers and I want to avoid concurrency issues.

FYI, if all of the parallel consumers are only reading data (e.g. `SELECT` queries) then you can't have concurrency issues and won't have deadlocks regardless. But if it's possible that data is written to the table concurrent to when it's being read from then it is possible and implementing proper indexes reduces the chances for issues.

Comment: Thank you for the help JD and yes you're right after the select there is a write to that row that is found to increment the `daily_value` field. do you recomend to use a SELECT FOR UPDATE in this case? I'm thinking about doing that way to avoid inserting in the table with a different state from when the select was made

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
make decisions based on the values from the SELECT
[optionally] UPDATE/DELETE ...;
COMMIT;
```

This avoids any 'race' conditions between concurrent connections.

As already mentioned, if you are only `SELECTing` then "transactions" (`START`, `FOR UPDATE`, `COMMIT`, etc) don't matter.

For your query, *start* a composite index with the columns tested with `=`, not the `date`.  If you start with `date`, the rest of the columns won't be acted upon for filtering (`WHERE`).